# Edgeブラウザでseleniumを使用できない

Tags: python, selenium

Edgeブラウザでseleniumを使用しようとする際に
以下のようなエラーがありました。

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found
```

調べるとブラウザとWebdirverのバージョン違いによってこのエラーが出るそうなのですが
奇妙なことに、ブラウザのEdgeのバージョンは89.0.774.50で、Webdriverと同じです。
これは他に何の原因が考えられますでしょうか？

Comment: この辺の記事のように発生している現象・環境・ソース等の情報を追記してみてください。[MSEdgeDriver - session not created: ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66479396/9014308), [Selenium Edge WebDriver (Chromium) ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62006471/9014308), [selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57092707/9014308) 今はDev版ですがLinuxとかもあるので。[Edgedriver 88.0.685.3 can't run Edge-dev browser ...](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/157631/edgedriver-8806853-can39t-run-edge-dev-browser-880.html) あとマルチポスト? [Edgeブラウザでseleniumを使用できない](https://teratail.com/questions/327467)

Comment: macOS上での動作のようですね。[I got the error session not created: No matching capabilities found by Selenium Edge WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66596620/9014308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記の文を書いたところうまく行きました！ MAC OSではこのように書く必要があるんですね。

```
desired_cap={}

driver = webdriver.Edge(('/Users/mymac/Downloads/edgedriver_mac64/msedgedriver', capabilities=desired_cap)
```